# Using google-vr from the fmod c++ api

Tags: c++, google-vr, fmod, google-vr-sdk

I try to use FMOD C++ Api in combination with google-vr (gvr). (Without any game engine)
But I get an error when trying to load a bank, which utilizes the gvr plugin:
Error Message from FMOD API:

```
[WRN] PluginEffectModel::init                  : Missing DSP plugin 'Google GVR Source'
```

However, I have no idea how I can tell the FMOD lib how to use the gvr plugin.
I assume there must be some kind of import for the gvraudio.dll, but I dont have any .lib or include sources.
So the question:
What are the required steps to be able to load FMOD banks which utilize gvr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always you find the answer immediately after asking...
Plugins have to be loaded through the API, not linked as I thought.

Thus the solution is the function from the FMOD lowlevel API.

```
    FMOD_RESULT System::loadPlugin(
      const char *filename,
      unsigned int *handle,
      unsigned int priority
    );
```